# How to filter very sparse features from a data set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am try to preprocess a data set and I'd like to delete very sparse columns by setting a threshold such that columns with values less than that have entries fewer than the threshold will be removed.

The code below should get the job done but I do not understand how it works, kindly assist with an explanation or suggestions on how I can get this done. Thanks!

```
sparse_col_idx = ((x_sparse > 0).mean(0) > 0.05).A.ravel()
```

x_sparse has dim of (12060, 272776)

Comment: What is `x_sparse`? A DataFrame or an ndarray?

Comment: you need to provide a small and representative data structure to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @ayhan it is a scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix. I guess it can be treated as a numpy array?

Comment: Ah OK. I asked because neither a Series nor an ndarray has an attribute called `A`.  That must be a scipy thing. Let me add the tag.

Comment: It looks like it converts a numpy matrix to a numpy array https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break this down into steps. Assuming x_sparse is a DataFrame then `x_sparse > 0` will return a DataFrame with the same exact dimensions, index and columns with each value as True or False based on  the condition given (here is where the value > 0)

```
.mean(0)
```

This takes the mean of each column. Since False evaluates as 0 and True evaluates 1, `mean()` returns the percentage of the column that meet the criteria. You are down to a Series at this point, where the column names are the index and values are the percentage that meet the criteria.

```
> 0.05
```

This now changes the previous Series to a Series of booleans that match the column names meeting the criteria.

```
.A.ravel()
```

This doesn't look necessary. I will come up with a simple example below to show the steps.

Create a DataFrame with random normal values

```
np.random.seed(3)
x_sparse = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(100, 5), columns=list('abcde'))
print(x_sparse.head())
```

output:

```
          a         b         c         d         e
0  1.788628  0.436510  0.096497 -1.863493 -0.277388
1 -0.354759 -0.082741 -0.627001 -0.043818 -0.477218
2 -1.313865  0.884622  0.881318  1.709573  0.050034
3 -0.404677 -0.545360 -1.546477  0.982367 -1.101068
4 -1.185047 -0.205650  1.486148  0.236716 -1.023785

# the argument 0 is unnecessary. The default is get average of columns
(x_sparse > 0).mean()
```

Output

```
a    0.48
b    0.52
c    0.44
d    0.55
e    0.45

# create a threshold
threshold = .5
(x_sparse > 0).mean() > threshold
```

Output

```
a    False
b     True
c    False
d     True
e    False
```

Keep specific columns

```
threshold = .5
keep = (x_sparse > 0).mean() > threshold
x_sparse[x_sparse.columns[keep]]
```

Output

```
          b         d
0  0.436510 -1.863493
1 -0.082741 -0.043818
2  0.884622  1.709573
3 -0.545360  0.982367
4 -0.205650  0.236716
```